# create new column of incremental number based on 2 categorical columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the columns `username` and `phase`. I want to create a separate column called `count` with incremental values.

The `count` will be based on how many times a `username` has appeared in a specific `phase`. How can I accomplish this efficiently? Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
    username  phase      count
0    andrew    1          1
1    andrew    1          2
2    alex      1          1
3    alex      2          1
4    andrew    1          3
5    cindy     3          1
6    alex      2          2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) after groupby on `username` and `phase`.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['username', 'phase']).cumcount()+1
print(df)
```

---

```
  username  phase  count
0   andrew      1      1
1   andrew      1      2
2     alex      1      1
3     alex      2      1
4   andrew      1      3
5    cindy      3      1
6     alex      2      2
```